# Hadoop Single Node installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and trying to get a single node setup of Hadoop 0.20.2 on my Windows 7 machine.

My questions are two-fold - one with respect to the completeness of the installation itself and the other regarding the error in the reduce stage of a sample Word Count program.

My Installation steps are as follows:

I am following http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2011/01/installing-hadoop-0210-on-windows.html for the installation procedure.

I have installed cygwin and set up password-less ssh on my localhost
My java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

Contents of conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Contents of conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Contents of conf/mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I set the JAVA_HOME variable and the command "hadoop version" prints 0.20.2
hadoop namenode -format creates the DFS without any errors

start-all.sh prints that namenode, secondarynamenode, datanode, jobtracker and tasktracker have all started.

however, the command "jps" prints:

```
$ jps
4584 Jps
11008 JobTracker
2084 NameNode
```

I noticed in that jps printed the pids' of tasktracker, secondarynamenode as well.

I am able to view the output of

```
http://localhost:50030 for the jobtracker, 
http://localhost:50060 for the tasktracker and 
http://localhost:50070 for the namenode.
```

I tried both put and get commands to the hdfs and they were successful:

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir In
bin/hadoop fs -put *.txt In
mkdir temp
bin/hadoop fs -get In temp
ls -l temp/In
$ ls -l temp/In/
total 365
348624 Mar 24 23:59 CHANGES.txt
13366 Mar 24 23:59 LICENSE.txt
101 Mar 24 23:59 NOTICE.txt
1366 Mar 24 23:59 README.txt
```

I could also view these files by browsing the DFS via the http interface for namenode

1. Is my installation complete?
2. If yes, why does the jps command not show the pids of all five components?
3. If not, then, what steps do i need to complete the installation?
4. What are other sanity checks used to test the completeness of the installation?

I initially believed my installation to be complete and ran a sample WordCount map-reduce program along the lines of http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2010/06/writing-your-first-map-reduce-program.html

I obtain the following output:

```
12/03/25 00:10:26 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/03/25 00:10:26 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/03/25 00:10:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201203242348_0001
12/03/25 00:10:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/03/25 00:10:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/03/25 00:21:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203242348_0001_r_0
00000_0, Status : FAILED
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
12/03/25 00:32:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203242348_0001_r_0
00000_1, Status : FAILED
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
12/03/25 00:44:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201203242348_0001_r_0
00000_2, Status : FAILED
Shuffle Error: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201203242348_0001
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 12
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=4
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed reduce tasks=1
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=13366
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=23511
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=244
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=1887
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=19699
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
12/03/25 00:55:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=1887
```

The map task seems complete, but the reduce task shows the following error in the logs:

```
2012-03-25 00:10:35,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0: Got 1 new map-outputs
2012-03-25 00:10:40,193 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 1 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-03-25 00:10:40,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: header: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0, compressed len: 23479, decompressed len: 23475
2012-03-25 00:10:40,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Shuffling 23475 bytes (23479 raw bytes) into RAM from attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:11:35,194 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 1 is already in progress
2012-03-25 00:11:35,194 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-03-25 00:12:35,197 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 1 is already in progress
2012-03-25 00:12:35,197 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-03-25 00:13:35,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Need another 1 map output(s) where 1 is already in progress
2012-03-25 00:13:35,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-03-25 00:13:40,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Failed to shuffle from attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:239)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:680)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2959)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFileInputStream.doRead(IFileInputStream.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFileInputStream.read(IFileInputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.shuffleInMemory(ReduceTask.java:1522)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.getMapOutput(ReduceTask.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.copyOutput(ReduceTask.java:1261)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1195)
```

The following are the contents of the task tracker logs:

```
2012-03-25 00:10:27,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2012-03-25 00:10:27,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0
2012-03-25 00:10:27,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0
2012-03-25 00:10:28,453 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_m_625085452
2012-03-25 00:10:28,454 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201203242348_0001_m_625085452 spawned.
2012-03-25 00:10:29,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_m_625085452 given task: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0
2012-03-25 00:10:29,523 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0 0.0% setup
2012-03-25 00:10:29,524 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0 is done.
2012-03-25 00:10:29,524 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0  was 0
2012-03-25 00:10:29,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2012-03-25 00:10:29,718 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201203242348_0001_m_625085452 exited. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2012-03-25 00:10:30,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/jobcache/job_201203242348_0001/attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0/output/file.out in any of the configured local directories
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: About to purge task: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0 done; removing files.
2012-03-25 00:10:30,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: Map ID attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0 not found in cache
2012-03-25 00:10:31,077 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_m_-1399302881
2012-03-25 00:10:31,077 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201203242348_0001_m_-1399302881 spawned.
2012-03-25 00:10:31,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_m_-1399302881 given task: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0 1.0% 
2012-03-25 00:10:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0 is done.
2012-03-25 00:10:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0  was 0
2012-03-25 00:10:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2012-03-25 00:10:32,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201203242348_0001_m_-1399302881 exited. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2012-03-25 00:10:33,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2012-03-25 00:10:33,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:33,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:34,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_r_625085452
2012-03-25 00:10:34,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201203242348_0001_r_625085452 spawned.
2012-03-25 00:10:34,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201203242348_0001_r_625085452 given task: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:40,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Sent out 23479 bytes for reduce: 0 from map: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0 given 23479/23475
2012-03-25 00:10:40,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 192.168.1.33:50060, dest: 192.168.1.33:60790, bytes: 23479, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:10:41,153 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2012-03-25 00:10:44,158 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2012-03-25 00:16:05,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Sent out 23479 bytes for reduce: 0 from map: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0 given 23479/23475
2012-03-25 00:16:05,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 192.168.1.33:50060, dest: 192.168.1.33:60864, bytes: 23479, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, cliID: attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000000_0
2012-03-25 00:16:05,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2012-03-25 00:16:08,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% reduce > copy > 
2012-03-25 00:21:25,251 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task: attempt_201203242348_0001_r_000000_0 - Killed due to Shuffle Failure: Exceeded MAX_FAILED_UNIQUE_FETCHES; bailing-out.
```

I had opened the ports 9000 and 9001 in the windows firewall
I checked the telnet output to verify that these ports were indeed open:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a -n | grep -e "500[367]0"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50030          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50060          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50070          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:50030             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:50060             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:50070             [::]:0                 LISTENING

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a -n | grep -e "900[01]"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:60332        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         127.0.0.1:60987        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9001         127.0.0.1:60410        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60332        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60410        127.0.0.1:9001         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60987        127.0.0.1:9000         ESTABLISHED
```

Could you help with both the issues of installation and getting the reduce task to work?

I looked at

```
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
```

and a few other links and tried the suggestions, but without any success.

I appreciate your patience in reading this post and would be happy to provide additional details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line in your logs:

```
2012-03-25 00:10:30,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/jobcache/job_201203242348_0001/attempt_201203242348_0001_m_000002_0/output/file.out in any of the configured local directories
```

I am guessing that you need to check `hadoop.tmp.dir` and `mapred.local.dir`. You mentioned about the configs that you are using and so the values of these two params is default. The default values of these params is given [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/core-default.html). Set those to some relevant location and try again.

NOTE: Before you this change, you need to stop hadoop and start after you are done.

Comment: I tried setting explicit values: /tmp/hadoopuser/mapredtmp and /tmp/hadoopuser/hadooptmp , and i verified that the actual output of the map task is present in the location, but i still get the same error as before.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6958 mentions that this bug is still unresolved in 0.20.2 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5194 has resolved this in 0.21